# Why am I getting the count value as zero of the counting class I am expecting it to be 20?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am expecting the output as 20 since there are two threads and the "counting" class method "counter" is also synchronized.

```
 class Counting{
     public int count ;
     public synchronized void counter(){
        count = count + 1;
    }
}

class mulA implements Runnable{
    public void run() {
        Counting obj = new Counting();
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++) {
            obj.counter();
        }
    }
}

class mulB implements Runnable{
    public void run() {
        Counting obj1 = new Counting();
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++) {
            obj1.counter();
        }
    }
}

public class MulTi {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        mulA obj2 = new mulA();
        mulB obj3 = new mulB();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(obj2);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(obj3);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        Counting obj4 = new Counting();

        System.out.println(obj4.count);

    }

}
```

How will i get the output as 20.Please tell me about my error.

Answer (score 2):

Each instance of class `Counting` has its own `count` variable, you could make it `static` if you want all instances to increment the same value.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `getCount()` method to you `Counting` class to return the count.
And also add a `getCount()` method to you `mulA` and `mulB` classes to return the count from their respective `Counting` objects.

Then you get both counts with `obj2.getCount()` and `obj3.getCount()`

So your modified code would look like this:

```
class Counting {
    private int count ;
    public synchronized void counter() {
        count = count + 1;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}

class mulA implements Runnable {
    private Counting obj = new Counting();
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++) {
            obj.counter();
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return obj.getCount();
    }

}

class mulB implements Runnable {
    private Counting obj = new Counting();
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++) {
            obj.counter();
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return obj.getCount();
    }
}

public class MulTi {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        mulA obj2 = new mulA();
        mulB obj3 = new mulB();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(obj2);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(obj3);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        System.out.println("Total 1: " + obj2.getCount());
        System.out.println("Total 2: " + obj3.getCount());
        System.out.println("Grand total: " + (obj2.getCount() + obj3.getCount()));
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** There is no shared resources as both your mul objects have their own `Counting` object. You do not need the **synchronized** keyword here.

It outputs

```
Total 1: 10
Total 2: 10
Grand total: 20
```

**Bonus:**

Here is a version with only one `Mul` class that you can configure to count to as many as you want.

```
class Counter {
    private int count = 0;
    public void incrementCounter() {
        count = count + 1;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}

class Mul implements Runnable {
    private Counter obj = new Counter();
    private int countTo;

    public Mul(int countTo) {
        this.countTo = countTo;
    }

    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0;i<countTo;i++) {
            obj.incrementCounter();
        }
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return obj.getCount();
    }
}

public class MulTi {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Mul mul1 = new Mul(10000);
        Mul mul2 = new Mul(50000);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(mul1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(mul2);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        System.out.println("Total 1: " + mul1.getCount());
        System.out.println("Total 2: " + mul2.getCount());
        System.out.println("Grand total: " + (mul1.getCount() + mul2.getCount()));
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Total 1: 10000
Total 2: 50000
Grand total: 60000
```

**And one more bonus if you really want to use shared resources**
In this case all Threads will use the same counter, so you need the synchronized keyword

```
class Counter {
    private static int count = 0;
    public static synchronized void incrementCounter() {
        count = count + 1;
    }
    public static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}

class Mul implements Runnable {
    private int countTo;

    public Mul(int countTo) {
        this.countTo = countTo;
    }

    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0;i<countTo;i++) {
            Counter.incrementCounter();
        }
    }
}

public class MulTi {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Mul mul1 = new Mul(100000);
        Mul mul2 = new Mul(500000);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(mul1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(mul2);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        System.out.println("Grand total: " + Counter.getCount());
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Grand total: 600000
```

you will not get `600000` if it is not **synchronized**